# I want the button above the box with the time

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want the buttons to be positioned above the box, but i don´t know how to do it, i tried many thigs but didn´t work

[image]

Something like this, idk how to put those button above

[image]

[image]
This is my HTML Code

```
  <div id="clockdiv">
    <div id="time">
      <span class="minutes"></span>
      :
      <span class="seconds"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
      <div>
        <img src="imgs/stop.png"  class="btnStop" id="btnStop"/>
      </div>
      <div>
        <img src="imgs/play.png" class="btnPlay"  type="button" id="btnPlay"/>
      </div>
      <div>
        <img src="imgs/pause.png"  class="btnPause"  type="button" id="btnPause"/>
      </div>
      <div>
        <img src="imgs/play.png"  class="btnResume"  type="button" id="btnResume"/>
      </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my CSS

```
.btnStop {
  width: 30%;
  height: 30%;
  display: none;
}

.btnResume {
  width: 30%;
  height: 30%;
}

.btnPlay {
  width: 30%;
  height: 30%;
}

.btnPause {
  width: 30%;
  height: 30%;
  display: none;
}
```

Idk what to try, because im so useless with CSS

Comment: I would post also the HTML code and rephrase the title to focus on the position issue

Comment: Have you tried absolute positioning??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a perfect use-case for [css grids](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout)

With the little info you have provided I can only help you so much but I am sure you can customize my solution for your needs

```css
#container {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, max-content);
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#container > button {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}

#timer {
  grid-column: 1 / span 4;
  grid-row: 2;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <button class="btnPlay">▶️</button>
  <button class="btnPause">⏸️</button>
  <button class="btnStop">⏹️</button>
  <button class="btnResume">⏯️</button>
  <div id="timer">30:00</div>
</div>
```